# Why are my hyper references pink?

Tags: hyperref, color, pandoc

I have this in the heading of my document:

```
  \usepackage[unicode=true,
              colorlinks=true,
              linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

Yet the links look like this:

[image]

Why the pink color when it says blue in the preamble?

There are a number of other things in the full .tex [document](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/blob/master/intro-spatial-rl.tex); I used Pandoc to create this from the original [.Rmd file](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/blob/master/intro-spatial.Rmd), so perhaps that helps explain it. In any case, I want a more conventional blue link color!

Comment: You may want to change `urlcolor`...

Comment: Problem solved - you may as well post that as the answer - it's correct.

Comment: A strange default color though 0 any ideas how to change that?

Comment: P. 9 in the manual lists magenta as the default color for `urlcolor`.

Comment: It was influenced I think by the original default colours for visited links in browsers

Comment: Yay for `pandoc`!

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino an answer?

Answer (score 3):

If you check the LaTeX-template of pandoc via `pandoc -D latex`, you'll see

```
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true,
            bookmarks=true,
            pdfauthor={$author-meta$},
            pdftitle={$title-meta$},
            colorlinks=true,
            citecolor=$if(citecolor)$$citecolor$$else$blue$endif$,
            urlcolor=$if(urlcolor)$$urlcolor$$else$blue$endif$,
            linkcolor=$if(linkcolor)$$linkcolor$$else$magenta$endif$,
            pdfborder={0 0 0}
            $if(hidelinks)$,hidelinks,$endif$}
```

and

```
$if(toc)$
{
\hypersetup{linkcolor=$if(toccolor)$$toccolor$$else$black$endif$}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{$toc-depth$}
\tableofcontents
}
$endif$
```

Everything between to `$` is preprocessed by pandoc, mostly expanded to the respective variable except for the `$if...$`s etc., which means the variables `citecolor`, `urlcolor`, `linkcolor` and `toccolor` (the linkcolor in the TOC only) are used. So in your case you have to put

```yaml
linkcolor: blue
```

into your document's [YAML-header](http://pandoc.org/README.html#metadata-blocks) or provide one of `-M|V linkcolor=blue` or `--metadata|variable=linkcolor:blue`. Whether you use `M/metadata` or `V/variable` depends on whether you only want to affect the template (via `V`) or truly set/replace the metadata (via `M`) which might also influence any filters used or (though not in this case) be output in the resulting document.

Concerning `unicode=true`, the template has

```
\ifxetex
  \usepackage[setpagesize=false, % page size defined by xetex
              unicode=false, % unicode breaks when used with xetex
              xetex]{hyperref}
\else
  \usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\fi
```

in it, i.e. unicode is set to true unless you're compiling with XeLaTeX. If you don't want this, you'd have to modify the template itself, or the generated TeX-file.